# assess the time complexity of the following code in terms of theta

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I know the time complexity is n*log(n) , however I could only assess it with an integral for the inner loop to get an upper bound, how do I get a lower bound? to make it theta and not O?

```
S=0;
for( i=1; i<n; i++)
  for( j=0;j<n;j+=i)
      S++;
```

so line 1 is executed once, line 2 is executed n-1 times + 1 check without entering, each one of these n-1 times line 3 is executed n/i times and we get:
T= 1 + n + (n/1+n/2+...+n/n-1) =< 1+n+n *(integral of 1/x from 1 to n) = 1+n+n*log(n) . And that's big O, how about Omega?

Answer (score 0):

Let's decompose the function in the following way: `T(n) = 1 + n + n + n*S(n)`, where `S = sum(1/x from x=2 to n-1)`. Note that it is identical to what you wrote.

The function `f(x) = 1/x` is monotonically decreasing, therefore you can bound the sum `S` from above by `int(1/x from x=1 to n-1)` and from below by `int(1/x from x=2 to n)`. In both cases you get `log(n)` up to constant terms. For the lower bound `log(n-1)-log(1) = log(n-1)` and for the lower bound `log(n)-log(2)`.

If these bounds are not obvious picture the left and right Riemann sums of the integrals for a decreasing function.

You did use the lower bound, not the upper one, in your question, by the way. (Because `1/x` is decreasing, not increasing.)

Then adding that back into the expression for `T(n)` we have `T(n) >= 1 + 2n + n log(n) - n log(2)` and `T(n) <= 1 + 2n + n log(n-1)`. Both are asymptotically proportional to `n log(n)`, giving you the Theta class.